# Filter only working when data is synchronous

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

The filter seems to be waiting for two words to be present before matching the string. Here's the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded"  placeholder="Search all documents" ng-model="filter.all">
</div>
<ul class="list-group list-group-lg no-bg auto">
    <li ng-repeat="file in files | filter: filter.all" class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <span class="clear">
            <span>{{ file.values.title }}</span>
        <small class="text-muted clear text-ellipsis">{{ file.values.description }}</small>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, for instance, there's a file whose `file.values.title` is `conference policy`, and no other file matches close to that, either in the `title` or `description`.

The filter works when I type `conference p`, but only when the `p` is hit, yet this file is unique with just `con`.

I think that this is something to do with the data coming in asynchronously, because if I just specify the data in the conroller then it works fine. My controller code to pull it in asynchronously is like this:

```
activate();
function activate() {
    var contenttype = 'files';
    var order = 'title';
    var limit = 500;
    var page = 1;

    return Bolt.getRecords(contenttype, order, limit, page)
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.files = data.data.data;
            console.log($scope.files);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please make a fiddle

Comment: I've made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qz3bjd40/), however, it works in the fiddle, but not in my code.

Comment: Then first find what is causing the problem in your code.

Comment: I've found that it's got something to do with the data coming in asynchronously - question updated.